# Can I use variables across SCSS files?

Tags: css, variables, sass

I'm using different 'SCSS variables files' (bootstrap variables, company variables, project variables) so it's easy to re-use them in other projects. But it seems I can't use variables across files.

Example:

- In `company-variables.scss` I declared `$white: #fff;`
- In `project-variables.scss` I want to reuse the above variable like this `$body-color: darken($white, 20%);`
- I get the following error: `Undefined variables: "$white". $body-color: darken($white, 20%);`

I load my files like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-variables";
@import "company-variables";
@import "project-variables";
```

Paths are correct.

I'm pretty new to SCSS. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or is this not possible/not the way to go?

Comment: $body-color: darken($white, 20%); is wrong code

Comment: @Ranjithv In what way is it *"wrong"*? It's valid syntax.

Comment: Seems to work for all other variables. If I move all variables in one file everything works fine.

Comment: yes.. you not import the files.. because your $white variables is applying in another file.. so you should import company-variables in project-variables

Comment: Is this done with a simple @import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it , you should import @import "company-variables"; into @import "project-variables";

Or just use default white color from bootstrap like that: 
darken(theme-color("white"), 20%);

Comment: @import doesn't seem to work. It gives a 'variable not found' error in my reboot fie

Comment: Ok, with this small information i cannot give you much more info. Can you share with me your code definition ?

Comment: My compiler seems to do a bad job. Problem solved now. Thx.

Comment: Eventually didn't have to add the @import.

Any suggestions for a good compiler?
For the moment I use Brackets SASS for Brackets. Doesn't seem to be that reliable.

Comment: I use gulp , and works fine , also you can add and watcher , check this totorial : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-gulp-sass-using-the-command-line-if-youre-a-beginner-17729f53249/

Comment: Thx for the help @Marin Terziyski